# Returning matched values with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have seen a number of threads about returning rows based off of multiple conditionals, but I am struggling to wrap my head around the best way to do this is dplyr. I have a large dyadic data set and mock data below. I want to return the rows for each country1 value where x = 1 and y values are matched (10 in this case, but not 11).

```
country1 <- c("a", "a", "a", "a")
country2 <- c("b", "c", "b", "d")
x <- c(0,1,1,1)
y <- c(10, 10, 11, 10)
df <- data.frame(country1, country2, x, y)

df
country1 country2 x  y
a        b        0 10
a        c        1 10
a        b        1 11
a        d        1 10
```

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
group_by(country1)
filter(x==1, y == ?)
```

I would like to end up with

```
country1 country2 x  y
a        c        1 10
a        d        1 10
```

The data set has about 900,000 rows so I would like to match all matching y values, rather than writing out each value like y == 10 in the above example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(country1, x, y) %>%
 filter(n() == 2)

  country1 country2     x     y
  <fct>    <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        c            1    10
2 a        d            1    10
```

Comment: I hadn't thought to use frequency of occurrences. This returns 0 observations for my real data. If I understand the code above it looks for each time two occurrences of y occurs for the group?

Comment: It keeps combinations of country1, x and y columns with two cases. Can you please elaborate when it does not work?

Comment: I believe it is because the data are dyadic and they are should be grouped by another time variable that is causing all pairs to occur more than 2 times, I may need to alter the question.

Comment: That was it, thank you! I forgot to add the second time variable and it works if I add 
a time variable  "t" in the group_by section.